# Kivy to update input text from file browser

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, designer, kivy-language

I am trying to get the path of file in input box of the Root widget here is my code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from os.path import sep, expanduser, isdir, dirname
from kivy.garden.filebrowser import FileBrowser
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
class RootWidget(FloatLayout):
    file = 'enter zip path or select it'
    def open(self):
        print("doing")
        self.popup = Popup(title='Test popup',
                  content=self.explorer(),
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(600, 600))
        self.popup.open()
    def explorer(self):
        if platform == 'win':
            user_path = dirname(expanduser('~')) + sep + 'Documents'
        else:
            user_path = expanduser('~') + sep + 'Documents'
        browser = FileBrowser(select_string='Select',
                          favorites=[(user_path, 'Documents')])
        browser.bind(
                on_success=self._fbrowser_success,
                on_canceled=self._fbrowser_canceled)
        return browser

    def _fbrowser_canceled(self, instance):
        print ('cancelled, Close self.')
        self.popup.dismiss()

    def _fbrowser_success(self, instance):
        print(instance.selection[0])
        self.file = instance.selection[0]
        self.popup.dismiss()

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

and here is kivy file code

```
<RootWidget>:
    TextInput:
        text: root.file
        multiline: False
    Button:
        text: 'Load'
        on_press: root.open()
```

It open file browser and works fine on close it close and on select put the file path in console. but it didn't update the text placed in input box.

thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

use id instead of text like this

```
def _fbrowser_success(self, instance):
    print(instance.selection[0])
    self.file = instance.selection[0]
    self.ids.change.text = self.file
    self.popup.dismiss()

<RootWidget>:
    TextInput:
        text: root.file
        multiline: False
        id:change
    Button:
        text: 'Load'
        on_press: root.open()
```